# Redirected output of a process stucks

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7

I'm starting a 3rd party command line application from my C# program using this part of code.

```
// define Process Start Info and give filename of the 3rd Party app
ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName);
myProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
theProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;

// instantiate observer class that contains a function 
// (ProcessStandardOutput) that is run in separate thread
observer = new StreamObserver();

// create the thread            
outputObserverThread = new Thread(observer.ProcessStandardOutput);

// start the 3rd party console application
theProcess.Start();

// set the input stream (to send commands to the console app)
commandStream = theProcess.StandardInput;

// connect the output stream with the observer class
observer.SetOutputStream(theProcess.StandardOutput);
// start the observer thread
outputObserverThread.Start();

// send any command to the console app
SendCommand("init");
```

This is actually nothing special and has been taken 70% from C# documentation example.

It works so far. I can send commands using the SendCommand() to the console application and I'm getting the response back.
But at one point the output stream gets stuck. Meaning I do not get any text back and even the end of the previous textblock is missing.
Sending  commands that result usually in just one line of reply will not be passed to the stream.
A command that usually produces a hugh reply (e.g. "help") will "flush" the stream and I'm getting text through the stream (including the missing data)

This is the (stripped down) implementation of the StreamObserver which processes the output stream:

```
public class StreamObserver
{
    // Volatile is used as hint to the compiler that this data
    // member will be accessed by multiple threads.
    private volatile bool _shouldStop;
    private volatile StreamReader outputStream;

    // This method will be called when the thread is started.
    public void ProcessStandardOutput()
    {
        while (!_shouldStop)
        {
            string line = outputStream.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
    public void SetOutputStream(StreamReader stream)
    {
        outputStream = stream;
    }
}
```

Nothing magic here either....

Any idea what could cause the stream to get stuck and recover when hugh data is present?

**I have just counted the returned text. It looks like a block has to contain ~4k data before it is send to the output stream.
Does that ring any bell???**

Btw, I'm running on Windows 7 64bit and Use Visual Studio 2013 prof.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious in the code you posted. So the problem must be in the code you didn't post. You should update your question so that it includes a good code example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). In the meantime, changes I would make just to improve things generally: pass `theProcess.StandardOutput` to the `StreamObserver` constructor instead of providing `SetOutputStream()`; simply read to the end of the stream (`ReadLine()` returns null) instead of using a flag; and don't start the process until the observer is completely configured.

Comment: This is entirely normal.  Almost any program switches its stdout and stderr streams to buffered mode when they see that their output is redirected.  Much more efficient that way.  So output is sitting in the buffer until it overflows or the stream is closed.  Nothing you can do about it, except getting in touch with the original programmer and asking him to add flush() calls to his program.

Comment: @HansPassant: I had exactly that same problem in the past. Luckily the program in question was open source and I was able to just stick an extra `flush` in there to get things moving.

Comment: 4k should be the size of a memory page in your operating system. The page is filled up and passed to the next process - my understanding.

Comment: @User: these are C runtime buffers, not OS buffers, so there's no particular reason they should be one page in size.  (It's a nice round number, though, so it's entirely possible that they are the same - but probably only by coincidence.)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for your answers. The 3rd party app is unfortunately not available in source code nor will I contact the developer to add flush() command.
But the app writes it output in parallel into a file. (Which seems to be updated immediately, independent on buffer size).
I hope reading this log file is a feasible workaround to the the output.

Comment: Just to complete this issue: Reading the log file is also not a solution, because it seems to be buffered as well :-(    I'm just sending wrong commands to the 3rd party app to force "Unknown command" responses until the buffer is filled and I'm getting the wanted output. Not nice but the only solution I have figured out yet.